# Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username

Tags: email, smtp, sendgrid

I'm using Sendgrid package to send emails in laravel 5.It's working in localhost as well as EC2 cloud hosting, but when I moved to VPS account it's not working throwing error -> production.INFO: Message: Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "anand.v" using 2 possible authenticators customException Line No: 1321

Comment: My .env file details MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.sendgrid.net
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=anand.v
MAIL_PASSWORD=XXXXXXX

Comment: I have no idea what this question is about, but it seems unrelated to [swift] (the Swift programming language).

Comment: OK Thanks. It's related to sendgrid smtp and email

Comment: I contacted to milesweb(VPS Account) for support, they are checking.It is working perfectly in local as well as ec2 hosting.Same thing I migrated to VPS.